# The weak type (1,1) estimate for the Hilbert transform

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, integral-transforms

I'm reading proofs that $H$, the Hilbert transform, is weak-$(1,1)$, so I'd like to show that there is a constant $C>0$ such that
$$| \{|Hf| > \lambda\}| \le \frac{C}{\lambda} \|f\|_{L^1}$$
for all $\lambda > 0$ and  $f \in L^1([-\pi,\pi]).$

All the proofs start by assuming that $ \|f\|_{L^1} < \lambda$ , why it is enough to discuss this case only? Any justification please!

Comment: It is enough, since you can just substitute $f$ with $f/\lambda$.

Comment: can you clarify more please? so when $ \|f\|_{L^1} > \lambda$ what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that for the inequality in question is equivalent to
$$
\left| \left\{ \left| H\left(\frac{f}{\|f\|_{L^1}}\right) \right| > \frac{\lambda}{ \|f\|_{L^1}} \right\} \right| \leq C \frac{\|f\|_{L^1} }{\lambda}.
$$
for all non-trivial functions $f\in L^1$. Now for $\lambda \geq \|f\|_{L^1}$, the right-hand side becomes larger, while the left-hand side becomes smaller. For this reasons, it suffices to prove that it for $\|f\|_{L^1} < \lambda$. In fact, by setting, $g= f / \lambda$, where $f \in L^1$ and $\lambda >0$, the weak-type inequality is equivalent to establishing that

$$
\left| \left\{ \left| H(g) \right| > 1 \right\} \right| \leq C 
$$
for every $g \in L^1$ with $\|g\|_{L^1}=1$. In other words, it just a standard normalization using a scaling and homogeneity argument, which allows to "disregard" the parameter $\lambda >0$.

Comment: @ks1 I have updated my answer now. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Just a quick check  the right-hand side becomes larger or smaller since we have $f/\lambda <1$ ?

Comment: The right-hand side becomes larger due to $\|f\|_{L^1}/ \lambda \leq 1$, while the lefthand side becomes smaller, since the set is smaller, attributed to the same reason.